# huge post data does not receive at controller

Tags: zend-framework

when i submit a form with less data it is saved correctly and everything goes fine, but when i post huge amount of data, controller is called and a blank white page comes up and nothing happens. Please tell me where can be this problem

Comment: Do `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` PHP variables allow you to sent a lot of data?

Comment: Just a second, qwert, we will enable our telepathy modules.

Comment: What do you have in your logs?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in development stage . So it will atleast throw the errors.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

The above will help you to see the errors thrown, to trace whether it exceeds max_execution_time or like as @Marcin says its having issue with max upload size .

Hope this will help you to trace it out .

Comment: thanks for your kind reply, after implementing this i will update the result

Comment: Did you get the desired result ?